# Conditional height for detailSection on Telerik Report Designer?

Tags: sql, telerik, report

I have a report I'm creating using Telerik Report Designer. The report will include rows that may or may not have an image attached to them. The DataSource is pulling in a Field called `ImgURL` that will hold the url to access/view the image.

If there's no image then `ImgURL` will equate to `NULL`. Now, I want to dynamically change the height of the detailSection (essentially, the height of each row) so that it "shrinks" if there's no image, otherwise expand the height.

I went to the DataBinding section for the detailSection and added the following expression:

`= IIf(Fields.ImgURL = NULL, "0.4in", "1.182in")` And set that against the Height.

However, the detailSection doesn't seem to change regarding the value of `Fields.ImgURL` it seems like even just placing the pictureBox alone will occupy space. How can I conditionally change the height?

**NOTE:** I've already added an expression to hide the pictureBox (visibility) if `ImgURL` is `NULL`.

Comment: Does setting the picture size mode to auto and can-shrink of detail-section to true helps?